# I Need Help Figuring out how to color text without a border in ImGui Code

Tags: imgui

I need help with text color. I have this currently:

```
    ImGui::SetCursorPos(ImVec2(10, 45));
    ImGui::Text("Cheat Status"); 

    ImGui::SetCursorPos(ImVec2(10, 65));
    char txt_green [] = "Undetected";
```

When I build it, it comes out with this weird border, which I don't know how to get rid of without changing ALL my borders:

[image: Output]

Does anyone know how to get rid of the border?

Comment: To change the text color in ImGui without a border, you can use the `ImGui::TextColored()` function. This function allows you to set the color of the text without the border.

Comment: Where is your code that passes `txt_green` to ImGui?